run `!ollama run llama3` in colab raise err "Error: could not connect to ollama app, is it running?"
I use following code
!apt install pciutils -y
!curl -fsSL https://ollama.com/install.sh | sh
!ollama run llama3

in !ollama run llama3 code cell, it raise err "Error: could not connect to ollama app, is it running?"

You need to launch Ollama before you can pull or run models, in the case of a local attempt, you would simply run (after installing Ollama):
ollama serve

And you would subsequently be able to run llama3:
ollama run llama3

I believe the latter command will automatically pull the model llama3:8b for you and so running ollama pull llama3 should not be mandatory.
However, my above suggestion is not going to work in Google Colab as the command !ollama serve is going to use the main thread and block the execution of your following commands and code.
Most tutorials using Google Colab seem to suggest to run ollama as an async process as in this accepted answer. I would suggest you use the code from the linked answer that runs Ollama in a separated thread based on the python modules threading and asyncio. As I just wanted to run a quick test code, I managed to make it run in Google Colab with a simple subprocess command:
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen("ollama serve", shell=True)
!ollama run llama3


first you have to pull the model(llama3. etc) then run this command:
ollama run llama3

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If your service working different port
for example your /etc/systemd/system/ollama.service file is:
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ollama serve
Environment="OLLAMA_HOST=0.0.0.0:8000"
Environment="OLLAMA_KEEP_ALIVE=-1"

you have to use command like this:
OLLAMA_HOST=0.0.0.0:8000 ollama list

or
export OLLAMA_HOST=0.0.0.0:8000
ollama list
ollama run llama3


Overall, i really like the approach using xterm extension, as it provides useful logs during model run:
!pip install colab-xterm
%load_ext colabxterm
Open a terminal
%xterm

but here's another approach, using subprocess.
The benefit of this approach is to stop/start ollama process running whenever we raise/restart the code cell.
import subprocess
with subprocess.Popen(["ollama", "serve"]) as p:
    try:
      !ollama pull llama3.2
      #or !ollama list
      # or any code invoking ollama from python

    except Exception as e:
        p.terminate()
        raise e

decorator:
def ollama_runner(func):
    def inner(*args,**kw):
        with subprocess.Popen(["ollama", "serve"]) as p:
            try:
                return func(*args,**kw)
            except Exception as e:
                p.terminate()
                raise e

    return inner

usage:
@ollama_runner
def main():
    pass

CAVEAT:
it causes decorated code to run forever because it awaits for subprocess.Popen forever.
